# Continuous surjective map

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Does there exist a continuous surjective map from $\{(x, y)\in \mathbb{R^2} | x^2-y^2=1\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I was trying to work with taking one branch of the hyperbola and restricting the function to it. But I cannot understand how to proceed much further.

Comment: [This may be relevant.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve)

Comment: @Xander Henderson I'm sorry, I do not understand.

Comment: You can continuously map the hyperbola to the real line, then continuously map the real line to $\mathbb{R}^2$ via a space filling curve.  But you changed the question... you mean for $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^2$ to be the codomain?

Comment: @Xander Henderson Yeah, the range should be the real line.

Comment: In that case, why not just project each branch of the hyperbola to the $x$-axis, then translate the image sets so that they overlap?  Both projection and translation are continuous, and composition of continuous maps is continuous.  Or, even better, project to the $y$-axis.

Comment: @Xander Henderson I was doing exactly the same thing. But I have come to know that such a function cannot exist. I cannot see why.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71418/discussion-between-xander-henderson-and-mathmentalist).

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to project to the $y$-axis, i.e. define $\pi_y : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$ \pi_y((x,y)) := y. $$
This map will be continuous with respect to the usual topologies on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}$ (note that the preimage of an open set $U$ is a rectangle of the form $\mathbb{R}\times U$, which is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$), which means that the restriction of $\pi_y$ to the hyperbola will be continuous (with respect to the subspace topology).

To see that the map is surjective, note that if $y\in\mathbb{R}$, then the point
$$ \left( \sqrt{1+y^2}, y \right) $$
is in the hyperbola, as
$$ \left(\sqrt{1+y^2}\right)^2 - y^2= (1+y^2) - y^2 = 1. $$

But then $\pi_y$, restricted to the hyperbola, is a continuous surjection.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Ascribe points of hyperbola with $x>0$ to positive numbers and points with $x<0$ to negative ones. Also map $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$ to 0.

Comment: I don't understand how you have defined your map.  Can you please clarify?

Comment: Sure! it is a function like $f(x,y)$ that surjects the hyperbola part by part For example points $(1+\epsilon,\pm\sqrt{\epsilon(2+\epsilon)})$ are mapped to $\epsilon$ and $(-1-\epsilon,\pm\sqrt{\epsilon(2+\epsilon)})$ to $\epsilon$ for $\epsilon>0$. Also $(-1,0)$ and (1,0) are mapped to 0 in $\Bbb R$. Infact this answer is very general and includes many cases.

Comment: Not clear to me. :(

Comment: Take for example $f(x,y)=x^3-x$.

Comment: I still don't understand.  If $(x,y)$ is a point in the hyperbola, what is the image of $(x,y)$ under your map?

Comment: That's $f(x,y)= x^3-x$

Comment: Or as an another example take $f(x,y)=xy^2$

Answer (score 1):

Define $f: \mathbb R^2 \setminus (\{0\}\times \mathbb R)$ by

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} x&& x>0\\ x+2 && x<0 \end{cases}$$

Then $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R^2 \setminus (\{0\}\times \mathbb R).$ Since the hyperbola, let's call it $H,$ is contained in the domain of $f,$ $f$ is continuous on $H.$ Check that $f$ sends the right branch of $H$ onto $[1,\infty),$ and sends the left branch of $H$ onto $(-\infty,1].$ Hence $f|_H$ is a continuous map of $H$ onto $\mathbb R.$